# .dmg keeps re-mounting

Tags: macos, mac, installation, mount, unmount

I am facing a problem that a drive keeps being mounted on my mac.

It began when I have attempted to install software packages from my car cam manufacturer. It created a mounted drive for installing the .app file to "Applications", which I then unmounted it afterwards. Later I remvoed the .app file from "Applications" (dragged to Bin) because the program seems not working on my version of macos.

Software image link from manufacturer:
https://uvue.com.au/uploads/1/2/4/9/124960746/macviewer_va_0_2.dmg
https://uvue.com.au/uploads/1/2/4/9/124960746/conv_v1.0.3.dmg

However, I found that the drive keeps mounting itself after some time of idling. This happens as well when restarting (maybe also when sign-out and sign-back in as well, not sure because I seldom just log-off the machine).

[image: Mounted_Drive]

I tried to remove all content inside the mounted drive, and unmounted it again. But the drive still keeps mounting later, without content inside though.

[image: Mounted_Drive_No_Content]

[image: Mounted_Drive_Info]

I have no idea why this happens as I should have deleted everything already. It is a nuisance to keep unmounting the drive, and worse I am worrying that this is some kind of virus.

Grateful if you can advise on this bizzare behaivor, and if there is anyway to stop it for good, thank you very much.

Comment: Unmount, then delete the actual .dmg & empty the Trash, so it can't remount. As you've also attempted to change the structure of the mounted image [which I'm surprised it even let you do at all] then you might get issues trying to empty the Trash. Try it & report back. [The root cause is that something on the .dmg is atill considered 'busy', so the OS won't let you unmount it.]

Comment: @Tetsujin I have already emptied the bin before, but it still keeps mounting.

Comment: Please describe your  **exact** method. Once you've deleted the .dmg there is no way it can remount, so it's not being deleted.

Comment: Software is removed at first by dragging the .app file to bin and removed from machine immediately. Then when I observed that the drive keeps remounting even after repeated ejection, I open the content inside and removed all the file inside to bin and again removed the contents permanently. However the drive still keeps mounting. To supplement I also did a Spotlight search as well, could not locate any file/folder with the software name.

Comment: So you haven't yet deleted the .dmg files you initially downloaded? They will be in your Downloads folder, assuming you haven't moved them, called macviewer_va_0_2.dmg & conv_v1.0.3.dmg respectively. I have no idea where the volume 'UVUE' comes from. It's certainly not in either of the .dmg files. I've tested install & removal of both apps, with no issues except it can't find the correct hardware, of course. Only remaining possibility I can think of is it's an SD card from your camera.

Comment: There is nothing in downloads folder as I usually download to desktop. DMG file is removed right after initial installation.

Comment: Did you double-check you have no other drives inserted? The mounted UVUE drive is nothing to to with the apps themselves or the installer .dmg files.. I've run both successfully - installed, run, discarded, no issues.. btw, to make it run first time you right click & select Open. if you just double-click it will refuse to launch.

Comment: You are right... this is the problem, my bad.
The included microSD card (having the manufacturing name "UVUE") stayed inside the slot. It was fitted inside so it's hard to observe it is still inserted. Thanks for helping with trouble-shoot.